# Histogram Equalization on image originally with logarithmic distribution

Tags: image-processing, histogram, normalization, probability-density

I have an image array which, because of the physical nature of the acquisition process, has a log distribution. What is the standard workflow for Histogram Equalization (HE) in this scenario: 1\apply HE directly; or 2\ apply log10(x) transformation and then HE?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try both approaches? Could you tell the difference in the output?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Visually, it doesn't look different, to be honest. But the two equalized histogram distributions differ a bit (specially on the central values).

Comment: That could be caused by quantization in the histogram computation. In theory, the result should be identical. If in doubt, do the simplest thing that gives you your answer (i.e. don't use the logarithmic transform).

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do you should transfer your histogram to the uniform one as much as possible (because in that case, the contrast is more visible for our visual system). As your distribution is like logarithmic curves, it is suggested to perform the inverse of logarithm first(you should know your logarithm base first) and then apply histogram equalization on it.